# Erro integração "Java" e "C" através de JNI

Tags: java, c, jni

Pessoal não estou conseguindo consumir funções de uma lib em "C" usando Java com JNI. Segue os meus artefatos e o erro gerado.

Classe `CalculadoraJNI`:

```java
public class CalculadoraJNI {
    // Declaração do método nativo:
    public native int calcula (int num1, int num2);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("calcula");
    }
```

Arquivo `TesteCalculadoraJNI.java`

```java
public class TesteCalculadoraJNI {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        CalculadoraJNI calc = new CalculadoraJNI();

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        int resultado = calc.calcula(num1, num2);
        System.out.println("A soma é: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Após a construção das classes executei a seguinte sequência de comandos:

```
javac CalculadoraJNI.java
javac TesteCaculadoraJNI.java
javah CalculadoraJNI
```

Arquivo gerado pelo comando javah CaculadoraJNI

```c
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    /* Header for class CalculadoraJNI */

    #ifndef _Included_CalculadoraJNI
    #define _Included_CalculadoraJNI
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    /*
     * Class:     CalculadoraJNI
     * Method:    calcula
     * Signature: (II)I
     */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CalculadoraJNI_calcula
      (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif
```

Arquivo `calculaJNI.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CalculadoraJNI.h"

/*
* Método que executa a soma
*/
int calcula (int num1, int num2) {
    int resultado = num1 + num2;
    return resultado;
}

/*
* Método com a mesma assinatura do calculadoraJNI.h
*/
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CalculadoraJNI_calcula
        (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj, jint num1, jint num2)
{
    return calcula (num1, num2);
}
```

Compilacao do código "C":

```
gcc -o libcalcula.so -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include calculaJNI.c -fPIC
```

Erro gerado ao tentar executar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no calcula in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at CalculadoraJNI.<clinit>(CalculadoraJNI.java:5)
    at TesteCalculadoraJNI.main(TesteCalculadoraJNI.java:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, deve verificar se o parâmetro passado no método System.loadLibrary está correto e que a biblioteca realmente existe. Observe que a extensão da biblioteca não é necessária. Assim, se sua biblioteca é nomeado SampleLibrary.dll, você deve passar o valor SampleLibrary como um parâmetro.

Além disso, no caso de a biblioteca já está carregado pelo aplicativo eo aplicativo tenta carregá-lo novamente, o UnsatisfiedLinkError será lançada pela JVM. Além disso, você deve verificar que a biblioteca nativa está presente tanto no java.library.path ou na biblioteca de ambiente PATH do seu aplicativo. Se a biblioteca ainda não pode ser encontrada, tente fornecer um caminho absoluto para o método System.loadLibrary.

Para executar o aplicativo, use o argumento -Djava.library.path, para especificar explicitamente a biblioteca nativa. Por exemplo, usando o terminal (Linux ou Mac) ou o prompt de comando (Windows), execute o aplicativo, emitindo o seguinte comando:

> java -Djava.library.path = "" -jar

Comment: Matheus, obrigado pelo auxilio, porem a solução estava em apontar a variável de ambiente "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" para o diretório onde o biblioteca nativa estava. Pelo que pude perceber o método System.loadLibrary() observa essa variável para carregar o código em "C" (biblioteca nativa).